# How convert rate of cooling to temperature equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am given

T'[t] = r(T[t] - S) where r is the proportionality constant.

The refrigerator temperature (S) is held at 42 degrees.

The originial temperature of the bottle of liquid is 80 degrees. T[0] = 80.

The bottle of the beverage has cooled to 63 degrees after 10 minutes.

I need to find the equation T[t] so that I can find the temperature of the bottle after t minutes.

What I have done:

T'[t] = r(T[t] - S) can be rewritten as T'[t] = rT[t] - rS

rT[t] can be rewritten as k e^(rt)

so now we have T'[t] =  k e^(rt) - rS

T[0] = 80 so k must be 80 and S=42 so now we have

T'[t] =  80 e^(rt) - r42

How can I find the function T[t] from this? I am not sure if I am doing it correctly.

Comment: I think you've there is some confusion as you've muddled up some steps and some of the things you have done don't make sense. You can solve this two ways. The first is to use an integrating factor $e^{-rt}$ i.e

$$T' - rT = -rS \implies (e^{-rt} T)' = -re^{-rt}S$$

or you can use the fact that your ODE is separable and solve that way i.e

$$\frac{dT}{T - S} = r dt \implies \ln(T - S) = rt + C$$

Comment: I'm not sure I follow how you got to the separable expression

Comment: ln(T-S) = rt +C does not make sense to me

Comment: \begin{align}
T' &= r(T-S) \\
\implies \frac{T'}{T-S} &= r \\
\implies \int \frac{T'}{T-S} dt &= \int r dt \\
\end{align}

Now, use that $$\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} dx = \ln(f(x))$$ Here, we have that $(T-S)' = T'$ as $S$ is a constant, hence

\begin{align}
\int \frac{T'}{T-S} dt &= \int r dt \\
\implies \ln(T-S) = rt + C
\end{align}

for some unknown integration constant $C$. Now exponentiate both sides and solve for $T$.