# How is $\frac{dT}{(T-S)} = r \,dt$ equivalent to $\ln(T-S) = rt +C$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

In the expression $\frac{dT }{T-S} =  r(dt)$ how is this equivalent to

$$\ln(T-S) = rt +C$$

this is related to Newtons law of cooling.

see [How convert rate of cooling to temperature equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2335642/how-convert-rate-of-cooling-to-temperature-equation?noredirect=1#comment4808572_2335642)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose $S$ and $r$ are not variables related to either $T$ or $t$.
$$\frac{dT}{T-S} = rdt$$
$$\frac{d(T-S)}{T-S} = rdt$$

Now integrate both sides will give you the desired result.

$$\int \frac{d(T-S)}{T-S} = \int rdt$$

$$\ln{|T-S|} +C_1= rt +C_2$$

$$\ln{|T-S|} = rt +C_2-C_1=rt +C$$